# Quartile for Boxplot::MSSQL 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have following table structure with around 3mn data points in MSSQL 2008 R2 database.

```
vertical|Defects(F)|Defects(NF)|
--------------------------------
Billing |193       |678
Provi   |200       |906
Billing |232       |111
Analyt  |67        |0
Provi   |121       |690
```

I need to calculate the Min, Max, First Quartile and Third Quartile to draw a whisker plot. Hence would want output in following format

```
vertical|Max       |Min      |Q1       |Q3
--------------------------------
Billing |343       |24       |103.75   |263.25
Provi   |811       |110      |285.25   |635.75
Analyt  |67        |67       |67       |67
```

Please note that Max, Min and quartile computation are done after adding Defects(F) and Defects(NF)

Please help!!

Comment: There are some functions which may do what you want like NTILE http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175126(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: @youbarajsharma : Do you have a date field in table ? Can you give sample input ? And what have you tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method works only if we have many rows of each type

q1min is minimum of 1st quarter (overal min)

q2min is minimum of 2nd quarter (first quartile)

q3max is maximum of 3rd quarter (third quartile)

q4max is maximum of 4rd quarter (overal max)

```
declare @my_table table (vertical varchar(50),[Defects(F)] int, [Defects(NF)] int);
insert into @my_table values ('Billing',193,678);
insert into @my_table values ('Provi',200,906);
insert into @my_table values ('Billing',232,111);
insert into @my_table values ('Analyt',67,0);
insert into @my_table values ('Provi',121,690);

insert into @my_table values ('Billing',111,678);
insert into @my_table values ('Billing',111,678);
insert into @my_table values ('Billing',111,678);
insert into @my_table values ('Billing',111,678);
insert into @my_table values ('Billing',111,678);
insert into @my_table values ('Billing',111,678);
insert into @my_table values ('Billing',111,678);

WITH cte as (
    select
        vertical,
        [Defects(F)]+[Defects(NF)] as defects
    from @my_table
),
PivotData AS
(
    select
        vertical,
        CASE WHEN quartile in (1,2) THEN MIN(defects) ELSE MAX(defects) END m,
        quartile
    from (
        select
            vertical,
            defects,
            ntile(4) over (PARTITION BY vertical order by defects) as quartile
        from cte
    ) i
    group by vertical, quartile
)
select vertical, [1] as q1min, [2] as q2min, [3] as q3max, [4] as q4max
FROM PivotData
PIVOT (SUM(m) FOR quartile in ([1],[2],[3],[4])) as p;
```